# EaselJS - Object above

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have 2 object on my stage and I want A object above B object (now is B above A).

```
function init() {
    // create stage and point it to the canvas:
    canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    // enable touch interactions if supported on the current device:
    createjs.Touch.enable(stage);

    // enabled mouse over / out events
    stage.enableMouseOver(10);
    stage.mouseMoveOutside = true; // keep tracking the mouse even when it leaves the canvas

    // load the source image:
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "ball.png";
    image.onload = handleImageLoad;

    var image2 = new Image();
    image2.src = "open-box.png";
    image2.onload = destination;
}
```

- var image  =  A
- var image2 =  B

Comment: Can you show the `handleImageLoad` and `destination` methods? Are you trying to put them above each other in the stack order, or above each other from top to bottom in pixels? Right now you have a race condition where they may load in a random order depending on what gets downloaded first. Maybe wait for both to be loaded, then add them to the stage in the order you prefer.

Comment: I can't, because stackoverflow gives error (many code.....) but you are right I want handleImageLoad (Method of object) above of destination (Method of object)